# How to replace or escape <tab> characters with \t in bash script and being able to output single quotes?

Tags: bash, shell, escaping

In the goal to create a file from a one line (bash) command, the goal is to output the contents of any text file - in this example a bash script - and wrap each line inside a command that is able to output that same line when pasted in a Terminal window.

Example source input file:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Example desired output:

```
echo 'Line 1';echo 'Line 2';echo 'Line 3';
```

Note: whether `printf`, `echo` or another command is used to create the output, doesn't matter as long as the source is human readable.

One hurdle were the single quotes, that would not be recreated. Therefore use the form **$'string'**, which are treated specially. The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.

Another requirement is to re-create tab characters from the old file in the new file. Therefore the wish is to **replace <\tab> characters with \t**.

Our tries to do this with `sed` or `tr` fail. How to replace tabs with their escape \t counterpart and still being able to output lines with original quotes?

Input file /Library/Scripts/BootRepairMount.sh contains:

```
$ cat /Library/Scripts/BootRepairMount.sh
#!/bin/bash
sleep 18
for OUTPUT in $(diskutil list | grep ':                  Apple_HFS' | awk '{ print $NF }')
do
    if [[ -z $(df -lnh | grep /dev/$OUTPUT) ]]; then
        echo "$OUTPUT is not mounted, repair and mount"
        diskutil repairVolume $OUTPUT
        diskutil mount $OUTPUT
    fi
done
```

The best shell one line command we could create is:

`$ oldifs=$IFS;printf '\n';printf '{';while IFS= read -r p;do [[ "$p" == *"'"* ]] && echo -n "echo $'$p';" || echo -n "echo '$p';"; done < /Library/Scripts/BootRepairMount.sh | tr '\t' '\134\164';printf '}';printf '\n\n';IFS=$oldifs`

Which returns this faulty output:

`{echo '#!/bin/bash';echo 'sleep 18';echo $'for OUTPUT in $(diskutil list | grep ':                  Apple_HFS' | awk '{ print $NF }')';echo 'do';echo '\if [[ -z $(df -lnh | grep /dev/$OUTPUT) ]]; then';echo '\\echo "$OUTPUT is not mounted, repair and mount"';echo '\\diskutil repairVolume $OUTPUT';echo '\\diskutil mount $OUTPUT';echo '\fi';echo 'done';}`

Desired output is:

`{echo '#!/bin/bash';echo 'sleep 18';echo $'for OUTPUT in $(diskutil list | grep ':                  Apple_HFS' | awk '{ print $NF }')';echo 'do';echo '\tif [[ -z $(df -lnh | grep /dev/$OUTPUT) ]]; then';echo '\t\techo "$OUTPUT is not mounted, repair and mount"';echo '\t\tdiskutil repairVolume $OUTPUT';echo '\t\tdiskutil mount $OUTPUT';echo '\tfi';echo 'done';}`

### Bash one line command version 2

`$ oldifs=$IFS;printf '\n';printf '{';while IFS= read -r p;do [[ "$p" == *"'"* ]] && printf 'printf $'\''%q'\'';' "$p" || printf 'printf '\''%q'\'';' "$p"; done < /Library/Scripts/BootRepairMount.sh;printf '}';printf '\n\n';IFS=$oldifs`

returns output that is heavy escaped:

`{printf '\#\!/bin/bash';printf 'sleep\ 18';printf $'for\ OUTPUT\ in\ \$\(diskutil\ list\ \|\ grep\ \':\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ Apple_HFS\'\ \|\ awk\ \'\{\ print\ \$NF\ \}\'\)';printf 'do';printf '$'\tif [[ -z $(df -lnh | grep /dev/$OUTPUT) ]]; then'';printf '$'\t\techo "$OUTPUT is not mounted, repair and mount"'';printf '$'\t\tdiskutil repairVolume $OUTPUT'';printf '$'\t\tdiskutil mount $OUTPUT'';printf '$'\tfi'';printf 'done';}`

that never gets unescaped back to its original values in Mac OS X 10.7.5.

```
printf '\#\!/bin/bash';
```

outputs:

```
\#\!/bin/bash
```

As well as:

```
echo -e '\#\!/bin/bash'
```

does output the unescaped value

```
\#\!/bin/bash
```

`-e` is not a valid command switch for the Mac OS X 10.7.5 `echo` command, according to its `man` page.

Comment: only wondering for what purpose you need one line "encoder" and one line "encoded script"...

Comment: @kobame: To create a one line (just copy and paste that line into a Mac OS X Terminal.app window) installer for a repair and mount drives script at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57169/how-to-auto-mount-internal-sata-hard-disk-drives-after-power-failure-interruptio/92743#92743

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash's builtin command `printf` has `%q` format code that handles this:

`printf '\n{ '; while IFS= read -r p; do printf "echo %q; " "$p"; done < /Library/Scripts/BootRepairMount.sh; printf '}\n\n'`

Unfortunately, it doesn't always choose quoting/escaping modes that're easy to read. Specifically, it tends to prefer escaping individual metacharacters (e.g. spaces) rather than enclosing them in quotes:

`{ echo \#\!/bin/bash; echo sleep\ 18; echo for\ OUTPUT\ in\ \$(diskutil\ list\ \|\ grep\ \':\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ Apple_HFS\'\ \|\ awk\ \'{\ print\ \$NF\ }\'); echo do; echo $'\tif [[ -z $(df -lnh | grep /dev/$OUTPUT) ]]; then'; echo $'\t\techo "$OUTPUT is not mounted, repair and mount"'; echo $'\t\tdiskutil repairVolume $OUTPUT'; echo $'\t\tdiskutil mount $OUTPUT'; echo $'\tfi'; echo done; }`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right you want paste *one long line* to the Terminal.app and want get the "source code" of original script. So, need a script what will generate the one-line script.

Maybe a bit unusual solution, but it is easy and simple.

here is the test script called `test.sh` (instead of your BootReapirMount.sh)

```
for i in {1..10}
do
    date
done
```

Here is the generator script `mkecho.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ ! -f "$1" ]] && echo "Need filename" && exit 1
asc=$(gzip < "$1" | base64)
echo "base64 -D <<<'$asc'| gzip -d"
```

Now, run:

```
bash mkecho.sh test.sh
```

you will get the next:

```
base64 -D <<<'H4sIAASwqFEAA0vLL1LIVMjMU6g21NMzNKjlSsnn4kxJLEkFMvJSuQBZFmY0HwAAAA=='| gzip -d
```

If you copy and paste the above into the terminal, it will will display the original `test.sh`

*Variant2*

If you want directly execute the script, you should modify the `mkecho.sh` to the next `mkeval.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ ! -f "$1" ]] && echo "Need filename" && exit 1
asc=$(gzip < "$1" | base64)
echo -n 'eval "$(base64 -D <<<"'
echo -n $asc
echo -n '" | gzip -d)"'
echo
```

When run

```
bash mkeval.sh test.sh
```

will get

```
eval "$(base64 -D <<<"H4sIAASwqFEAA0vLL1LIVMjMU6g21NMzNKjlSsnn4kxJLEkFMvJSuQBZFmY0HwAAAA==" | gzip -d)"
```

and finally when you copy and paste it into the terminal, you run the `test.sh` and will get:

```
Fri May 31 16:25:08 CEST 2013
... 8 lined deleted...
Fri May 31 16:25:08 CEST 2013
```

Warning: because the script is NOT TESTED for every possible conditions, nor for redirects and so on - I really **don't recommending** using the `eval` verision.

Comment: Base64 encoding outputs text that is not human readable, and therefore not desirable. Users may ask: what is this going to do to my computer when pasting this into my terminal?

Comment: sure, you're right. ;) but, afaik,  - your escaping isn't soo much clear... :)

Comment: The escaped version has another advantage: direct editing. No need to base64 re-encode on every change.

Comment: as i told - showed an alternative - you know what you want achieve :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\\t/\\/g'


$ echo 'ffsd \tif [[ -z $' | sed 's/\\t/\\/g'
ffsd \if [[ -z $
```

Comment: This doesn't solve, because the echo " echo $'$p'" or echo "echo '$p'" does convert the \t's back to tab characters in its output.